# Error creating Laravel project from command line

Tags: laravel

I installed phpmyadmin, node.js and composer.

In the terminal, I wrote: composer global require "laravel / installer" and after, to create my project I wrote: laravel new laravel (the name of my project is laravel) and when I do enter I have these Errors that appear.

[image]

Comment: Paste your errors, don't post an image

Comment: What happens when you try `laravel new laravel` instead of `laravel new "laravel"` (notice the quotation marks)

Comment: Your user and PHP process doesn't have access to write to the directory, the first warning in your install..

Comment: I think you dont have permissions for our user.Please repeat this steps with administrator command prompt please [check this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Are them right the paths with both slash and backslash directory separators?

Comment: When i try with quotation marks i have the same error

Comment: When i try with administrator command prompt, i have the same error again

Answer (score 0):

try to run as admin, change the permission to that folder or change the owner of that folder. Cause the error is saying that you don't have permissions to write in that folder.

---

**To run as admin:**

UNIX OS

prepend `sudo` to your command (but you shouldn't use composer as admin)

WINDOWS

Launch command line with this cli
`runas /noprofile /user:Administrator cmd` or right click on cmd application and `run as administrator`

**To change permission:**

run `chmod XXX FOLDERNAME` where `XXX` are the permission codes, 777 allow everyone to read/write. `FOLDERNAME` its the name of the folder or of the file.

**To change owner:**

run `chown -R user:group FOLDERNAME`
try with `chown -R marc:marc FOLDERNAME` the `-R` flag applies the ownership to the subfolders/files

Comment: sudo is for mac or pc? I have a pc with windows 10

Comment: Sorry that was for unix system not for windows. I'm updating the answer

Comment: Btw I think it will be better fix permission errors or you will encounter this issue each time you will try to run composer.

Comment: Sorry i'm a beginner with laravel
Someone can tell me how to change the permission please?

I'm on pc with windows 10

Comment: Did you install vagrant and homestead? Use vagrant machine and run cli `sudo chmod 777 FOLDERNAME` where FOLDERNAME is you folder

Comment: I do in the terminal : 

c:\sudo chmod 777 laravel (where laravel is my foldername) and the result is : 

"sudo" Is not recognized as an internal or external command, an executable program, or a batch file

Comment: You have to install Vagrant then use virtual machine in vagrant. So you can use Unix commands running virtual machine. If you don't know how to use command line try to simply click on the parent folder and set permissions with Graphic User Interface